# docker-compose: difference run, exec and what happens to the layers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

As far as I understood `docker` and `docker-compose` the flow is like that:

```
Dockerfile --build--> Docker Image --create--> Docker Container #1
                                   --create--> Docker Container #2
                                   --create--> ...
                                   --create--> Docker Container #n
```

So the `Image` is made by the commands in the `Dockerfile` but is purely some sort of "offline" version. You can bring it "online" then as a Container.

In my understanding `docker-compose up` is doing this 2-step process for us by the `service` definitions inside `docker-compose.yml`, beside some other stuff like mounting volumes, exposing ports and so on.

---

**My first question is:**

If I run `docker-compose exec some_command`, then I am manipulating the docker container - right?

As far as I have understood the documentation, `docker-compose run some_command` is doing nearly the same, but, it is creating a new "layer" beforehand, so sth. like this:

```
Docker Container #n (layer 0) ----> Docker Container #n (layer 1)
```

While the `some_command` is then executed on the layer 1 - right?
Furthermore it seems like `run` is passing `some_command` to the entrypoint, while `exec` does override the defined entrypoint.

**My second question is:**

What happens to the new layer created by `run` afterwards? Is there a way to execute the command without creating a new layer? I would like to know that because I added an entrypoint-script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$@" in
    "update")
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        ;;
    "start")
        python manage.py runserver
        ;;
    *)
        echo "executing $@"
        exec "$@"
        ;;
esac
```

I did so in order to be able to run some common tasks like setup, update, ... by running just a short command like `docker-compose run backend update`. The problem is that the layer that is created by `run` is not used if I run `up` afterwards.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First lets clarify the basic terms here. Citing from the [official docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#docker-objects):

> An **image** is a read-only template with instructions for creating a Docker container.

Basically an **image** is just a filesystem archive containing the files and directory structure and some additional metadata (like [`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) or [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)) for a container. So you may also think of it as a `tar` or `zip` archive.

> A **container** is a runnable instance of an image.

To start a new **container** from an image `docker` unpacks the image, sets up the respective [namespaces](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/#namespaces) and starts a process using the unpacked image as the filesystem root.

The [**layers**](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/) usually refer to the *layers* in the image created by the build process and are used to cache and reuse common files/layers in multiple images. So you should only need to care about them when [optimizing your build steps in the `Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache).

Instead of extracting/copying the image contents for each new container `docker` will only [add a thin writable layer on top of the image](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#container-and-layers) where changes for that container are stored.
The exact mechanics of this are an **implementation detail** and **depend on the used storage drivers**! For the most part when using `docker` you should not need to care about this.

---

Now on using `docker-compose`: what it basically does under the hood is to just build and execute the respective `docker` commands* to run and manage the containers required for your services based on your `docker-compose.yml` config file. So lets look into the relations of `docker-compose` to the respective `docker` commands:

- `docker-compose build`: will execute the respective `docker build` command for each service with a specified `build` option
- `docker-compose pull`: `docker pull`s the images for all services with an `image` option from the respective repository
- `docker-compose up`:

  - *if necessary*: will first `docker-compose build` / `docker-compose pull` all your services
  - starts the service containers by building and executing the respective `docker run` command
- `docker-compose exec`: will run `docker exec` to start a new process/command inside **an existing, running** container
- `docker-compose run`: starts **a new container** for interactively executing the specified command, i.e. executing `docker run`

* Note that `docker-compose` does *not actually* call the `docker` command but rather talks with the `docker` daemon directly using the API. But for easier understanding you can just pretend it does.

---

### With that now to your questions:

> If I run `docker-compose exec some_command`, then I am manipulating the docker container - right?
>
> As far as I have understood the documentation, `docker-compose run some_command` is doing nearly the same, but, it is creating a new "layer" beforehand, so sth. like this:

`docker-compose exec` will run inside your **existing, running service container** while `docker-compose run` will start **a new, independent container**.

> Furthermore it seems like `run` is passing `some_command` to the entrypoint, while `exec` does override the defined entrypoint.

Correct, `exec` does not use the entrypoint.

> What happens to the new layer created by `run` afterwards? Is there a way to execute the command without creating a new layer?

The changes are part of the container started by `run` and will persist until you delete *that* container. If you want to apply the changes to your service container (used by `docker-compose up`) however you need to run `docker-compose exec`!

> I would like to know that because I added an entrypoint-script like this:
>
> I did so in order to be able to run some common tasks like setup, update, ... by running just a short command like `docker-compose run backend update`.

Since `docker-compose run` will execute that command in a new container you need to run `docker-compose exec` instead calling the entrypoint manually:

```sh
docker-compose exec app /entrypoint.sh update

# and if you need to restart your app restart the service containers
docker-compose restart
```

**This however is the wrong way to use `docker`!** because containers are meant to be [ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers) and commands executed in a container would only affect that particular container. The changes would all be lost the moment you had to run a new container instance on that image (you stopped the container, power failure, etc).

Instead you should add the `update` command as (the last) command into your `Dockerfile` and rebuild (the last layer of) the image:

```sh
docker-compose up --build
```

Or if you have to skip the build cache to force a new build:

```sh
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Your answer was thw most precise snd clear, thank you very much

Comment: Superb answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

For the most part, the various imperative `docker-compose` commands are very similar to their `docker` equivalents, except that they know how to look up containers using a `docker-compose.yml` file and in some cases their defaults are a little different.

So, `docker-compose exec` is basically identical to `docker exec`.  It is a debugging tool that can run an additional command inside a running container.  It runs in the same environment as the container's main process, with the same container-private filesystem.  It is not a child process of the main process, and if the main process has an entrypoint wrapper script that sets environment variables, it won't get to see those.  The additional command is frequently a debugging shell, and `docker-compose exec` defaults to the `docker exec -it` options.

```sh
# Get a debugging shell in a running container:
docker-compose exec app bash

# Basically equivalent to:
docker exec -it project_app_1 bash
```

Similarly, `docker-compose run` is basically identical to `docker run`: it launches a new container based on the image specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file.  Unlike `docker run`, it inherits most of its options from the `docker-compose.yml` file, including network setup, environment variables, and mounted volumes (but not published ports).  Like `docker run`, the contents of the container filesystem are basically orphaned after the container exits (or deleted if you used the `--rm` option).

```sh
# Get a debugging shell to see how an image was built:
# (This will run via the image's entrypoint)
docker-compose run --rm app bash

# Basically equivalent to:
docker build -t project_app .
docker run -it --net project_default -v $PWD/logs:/app/logs \
  --rm project_app bash
# (Picking up the Compose networks: and volumes:)
```

The "update" task you're showing in the proposed entrypoint wrapper isn't something you'd do at container startup time.  If you need to update the code or library dependencies in the image, rebuild the image (maybe with `docker-compose build`).

```sh
# If the Dockerfile has...
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
...
```

```sh
# ...then you can get a container with updated library dependencies by
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: The last part of this answer is definitely the right thing to be doing

Answer (score 3):

The 'live' layer 1 you're referring to is an actual folder squirreled away in the host filesystem, which is what the running container sees as its world of files. These files are ephemeral and are removed as soon as the container is removed, unless they are committed into a compressed image layer beforehand.

There are therefore two kinds of layer - the live ephemeral one and the persisted committed ones. Usually only the latter are called layers, though you're right they're all layer-like if you squint a bit.

An ephemeral layer can be turned into a persisted one only if it is committed (can be done via `docker commit`)
, which is exactly what the `docker build` process does as it steps through the lines of the Dockerfile, running short-lived containers as it goes.

---

On question one: `docker exec` runs a new process in an existing squirreled-away folder as referred to above, whereas `docker run`, amongst other things, unpacks an archived image and sets up the 'online' files first. So basically you're completely right.

On question two: If you want to run your update command and then commit the container's ephemeral files that have been updated, you'll need to explicitly do `docker commit $containerId $newImageTag` after the `docker run` command has completed (but before the container has been removed - confused??)

Don't use `docker-compose` for this kind of container/image wrangling - use the `docker` command directly.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share an idea which caused data loss:

```
dirs=(
    conf
    ccnet
    seafile-data
    seahub-data
    pro-data
    seafile-license.txt
)

for d in ${dirs[*]}; do
    src=/shared/seafile/$d
    if [[ -e $src ]]; then
        rm -rf /opt/seafile/$d && ln -sf $src /opt/seafile
    fi
done
```

From the 01_create_data_links.sh file which is executed upon start of the container.
My understanding:
When every directory which still exists in /shared/seafile/ will trigger a delete from the /opt/seafile/ associated directory.
A docker container can be stopped and started which is a likely scenario ( Happened to me ). When a docker container is started again ( aka not created ) then it will delete of any important directory because the link still exists.

Thoughts?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35573112)